# Change Name of file after copy to new directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got a python script to update external excel link, then copy to a new directory but I want to prefix it with the date as its going to occur a few times a month. At the moment, the script only copies the file into the same directory and changes the name.

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
from datetime import datetime

prefix = datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d')
dir_src = ("D:\\Users\\cdoyle\\Desktop\\TGround\\")
dir_dst = ("D:\\Users\\cdoyle\\Desktop\\TGround\\GUID\\")
filename = ("All Facilities - GUID Duplicates Tracking.xlsx")
outputname = os.path.join(prefix + "-" + filename)
srcfile = ("D:\\Users\\cdoyle\\Desktop\\TGround\\All Facilities - GUID Duplicates Tracking.xlsx")
desfile = ("D:\\Users\\cdoyle\\Desktop\\TGround\\GUID\\All Facilities - GUID Duplicates Tracking.xlsx")

if os.path.exists(srcfile):
    shutil.copy( dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
    print(filename)

if os.path.exists(desfile):
    os.rename("D:\\Users\\cdoyle\\Desktop\\TGround\\GUID\\All Facilities - GUID Duplicates Tracking.xlsx", outputname)
    print (outputname)
```

Comment: I changed the filename variable to include the dir_dst path variable as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simply replace your last if with:

```
if os.path.exists(desfile):
    os.rename(dir_dist + filename, dir_dist + prefix+ '_' + filename)
    print (outputname)
```

If possible, avoid spaces in file and folder names. It could lead to some problems later.